# Invalid Post: 400 - Bad Request with Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, odata

I'm using PoliteMail's ODATA RESTful API (Doc: [PoliteMail API Entity Directory](http://kb.politemail.com/?p=1389))

I'm trying to create a Contact inside of PoliteMail with `requests.post()`.

Below are my steps

### Load Libraries

```
import requests
import json

# point to credentials
import os
import yaml
myKeys = yaml.load(open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents\keyfile2.json')))
```

### Authentication Creds

```
user = myKeys['PoliteMail'][1]['user']
password = myKeys['PoliteMail'][1]['password']
auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(user, password)

base_url = 'https://comm.microsoft.com/ssv3/odata/'
entity = 'Lists'
url = base_url+entity
```

### GET request

```
r = requests.get(url+'(56)', auth=auth)
print(r.status_code) # '200'
```

I can GET anything within this entity, but can't post.

### POST request

Below is the structure [given in the documentation](http://kb.politemail.com/?p=1337)

```
payload = {
"ID":"0",
"Name":"Test List",
"Description":"Does this work",
"IsNewsletter":"0",
"Shared":False, 
"CreationDate":"2014-11-19T23:00:00.000Z",
"ActiveState":"1",
"isAnonymous":False,
"BusinessID":"0",
"RegionID":"0"
}
```

My request:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload),auth=auth)
```

It's output

> 415: The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource."

But when I add a header for content type:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload),auth=auth,
                     headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

I'm told:

> 400 "The request is invalid." An error has occurred.\r\n","type":"","stacktrace":""

I've tried the following, to no avail:

- `json=` instead of `data=`
- removing quotes from num
- changing the ID value to something other than 0
- removing newline characters from the payload

Any help is much appreciated!

### Update

The errors are coming from the parsed text of the response below is the full response readout when I use `BeautifulSoup`

```
{
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"The request is invalid."
    },"innererror":{
      "message":"contact : An error has occurred.\r\n","type":"","stacktrace":""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create a list with your sample by fixing the capitalization of ***False*** to ***false*** and ***isAnonymous*** to ***IsAnonymous*** in the payload.

```
{
    "ID":"0",
    "Name":"Test List",
    "Description":"Does this work",
    "IsNewsletter":"0",
    "Shared":false, 
    "CreationDate":"2014-11-19T23:00:00.000Z",
    "ActiveState":"1",
    "IsAnonymous":false,
    "BusinessID":"0",
    "RegionID":"0"
}
```

You also mentioned creating a Contact at the beginning of your post. I was able to successfully create a Contact with the following.

```
{
      "DisplayName": "Test Test",
      "FirstName": "Test",
      "LastName": "Test",
      "Email": "test@politemail.com",
      "ActiveState": true,
      "CreationDate": "2017-09-12T0:49:23.303Z",
      "Shared": false,
      "OwnerID": 0,
      "CategoryID": 8,
      "StageID": 1,
      "Company": "",
      "WebAddress": "",
      "Title": "",
      "FileAs": "Test Test",
      "Source": 0,
      "Notes": "",
      "Custom1": "",
      "Custom2": "",
      "Custom3": "",
      "Custom4": "",
      "Custom5": "",
      "Custom6": "",
      "Custom7": "",
      "Custom8": "",
      "Custom9": "",
      "Custom10": "",
      "Custom11": "",
      "Custom12": "",
      "Custom13": "",
      "Custom14": "",
      "Custom15": "",
      "Custom16": "",
      "Custom17": "",
      "Custom18": "",
      "Custom19": "",
      "Custom20": "",
      "BusinessID": 0,
      "RegionID": 0,
      "LastChangedDate": "2017-09-12T20:49:23.303Z",
      "ListID": null
    }
```

I work at PoliteMail and have made an internal request to get the documentation updated to fix the capitalization of ***IsAnonymous***.

---

UPDATE: The documentation has been updated with the correct capitalization. http://kb.politemail.com/?p=1349

Comment: It was the IsAnonymous capitalization. the false/False discrepancy is taken care of by the json.dumps() function. Can I also recommend that the documentation replace curly quotes with straight quotes to make it easier to copy and paste?

Comment: Yes! I'll definitely pass that on.

Comment: Just got an update that all the curly quotes have been replaced with straight quotes in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

From the error log, server side may not handle the line break `\r\n`.

Can you try to remove the line break of your payload?

```
payload = {"ID":"0","Name":"Test List","Description":"Does this work","IsNewsletter":"0","Shared":False, "CreationDate":"2014-11-19T23:00:00.000Z","ActiveState":"1","isAnonymous":False,"BusinessID":"0","RegionID":"0"}
```

Comment: Great idea, but no dice. I updated my post with more detail about where I was getting the error message (i.e. Beautiful Soup). Any other ideas for me to try?

Comment: Have searched the document and reviewed your code, everything is good from my point of view.


Can you use the same payload and credentials by Postman (Google Plugin) and test if everything is good ?

Comment: I tried using Postman with settings and couldn't get it to work. I even fiddled with a lot of options to no avail. Do I need an Accept header?